# Flutter go_router: resume navigation after redirect (e.g. login)

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have a route, `/authenticated/page`, that can only be viewed once the user is logged in.

go_router's [official redirection example](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/redirection.dart) shows how to do such "login gate", but it redirects to `/`.

How do I resume navigation after redirect (e.g. login)? I.e.:

`/` → click link to `/authenticated/page` → blocked by login page → successful login → opens `/authenticated/page`

Comment: any updates on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I spent awhile trying to figure this out and here is what I came up with. I don't love the solution but it works...

For the routes I want to force login I check if the user is logged in:

```
GoRoute(
    path: "account",
    name: "/account",
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (authRepository.currentUser == null) {
        return const SignInScreen(redirectTo: "/account");
      }
      return const ProfileScreen();
    },
)
```

Notice when the currentUser is `null` this route redirects to the `SignInScreen` with the `redirectTo` set to "/account".

Then in the `SignInScreen()` create an optional `redirectTo` param which if set will redirect to that route after successful sign in.